# probability of striking the circular ring by gas molecules

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, differential-geometry, probability, kinetic-theory

In kinetic theory we use probabilistic case to derive pressure, no. Of molecules having speed c to c+dc or in such cases.and to derive such equations we introduce a term called "SOLID ANGLE"

I come to know that this is a kind of 3d angle or a closed angle like the angle surrounded by a cone towards its apex
And equation for solid angle is 
          dw=dAcosx/r^2
Although I don't know where the formula come from!
But this is a very useful indeed.
In kinetic theory it is used to determine the no. Of particles striking a unit area element dA

But I am a little bit confused about the solid angle cause it tells about the he angle of the cone but can I consider the angle of a pyramid towards its apex as it's base is a square not circle????

Always when we tell about solid angle we take the reference of the angle of a cone which has a circular base but why cone why not about a pyramid

1)in kinetic theory we consider the probability of molecule striking the elementary area dA is = dw/4π
But what will be the probability of molecule strike a circular ring not area,
Consider the circular perimeter of a cone???

2)in 2D what will be the probability  of molecule strike a unit length of boundary as I can not consider solid angle there cause solid angle can only be considered in 3D 
So what will be the 2D form of solid angle???

Comment: Please anyone solve my problem